# Bootstrap 5 - How to display inline text and progress bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

How I can display the text and the progress bar on the same line with bootstrap 5?

```html
  <nav class="navbar bg-light fixed-bottom">
    <div class="row m-0">
      <div class="col-12 countdown">
        <p class="text-muted d-inline pe-3">Elasped time:</p>
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" ref="elaspedTime" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
            {{ minutes }} seconds
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

I'm trying using `d-inline` class but not working as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The p element is at the same level as the progress div.
To get both on the same line using bootstrap you can make the col div to align with flex as a row adding these classes: .d-flex, .flex-row and .align-items-center.
The markup would be like this:

```
      <div class="col-12 countdown d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
        <p class="text-muted d-inline pe-3 mb-0">Elasped time:</p>
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" ref="elaspedTime" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
            {{ minutes }} seconds
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

You can check a working example at: [see example](https://codepen.io/ormasoftchile/pen/gOgyNZq)

Comment: I've seen the demo,it's what I'm looking for. I'm not an expert with front-end. I've noticed that I've missed the container but it's not a big problem I think?

Comment: A container is not needed for what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a navbar, try to put your code in a list. Example

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><p class="text-muted d-inline pe-3">Elasped time:</p></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
          <div class="progress-bar" ref="elaspedTime" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
            {{ minutes }} seconds
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```